# If three vector such $|a|^2=a\cdot b=b\cdot c=1,a\cdot c=2$,show that $|a+b+c|\ge 4$

Tags: inequality, vectors

Let three vector $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ such 
$$|\vec{a}|^2=\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=\vec{b}\cdot \vec{c}=1,\vec{a}\cdot \vec{c}=2$$

show that
$$|\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}|\ge 4$$

since
$$|a+b+c|^2=|a|^2+2(a\cdot b+\vec{b}\cdot \vec{c}+\vec{a}\cdot \vec{c})+|b|^2+|c|^2=9+|b|^2+|c|^2$$
it suffice to prove
$$|b|^2+|c|^2\ge 7$$
or
$$|b+c|\ge 3$$I just do it now

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given that, $a.b=1$ and $a.c=2$. Adding these two, we get,
$\vec{a}.(\vec{b}+\vec{c})=3$.
$\Rightarrow |\vec{a}||(\vec{b}+\vec{c})|cos\theta=3$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors $\vec{a}$ and $(\vec{b}+\vec{c})$.
Since, $cos\theta\le1\Rightarrow|\vec{a}||(\vec{b}+\vec{c})|\ge3 $. Now, use he fact that, $|\vec{a}|^2=1\Rightarrow |\vec{a}|=1$ to get, $|\vec{b}+\vec{c}|\ge3$

Answer (score 0):

The span $V$ of the three vectors is at most three-dimensional. We may chose an orthonormal basis of $V$ such that $a=(1,0,0)$ and $b=(1,p,0)$. The condition $a\cdot c=2$  enforces $c=(2,y,z)$, and from $b\cdot c=1$ it then follows that $2+py=1$. This can be done with any $p\ne0$ and $y=-{1\over p}$. Altogether we now have
$$a+b+c=\left(4,p-{1\over p}, z\right)\ .$$
It is obvious that this vector has length $\geq4$.